# When I am installing Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2013 in the package manager console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> Install-Package : The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\clientsidemanagement\entitydemo\packages\EntityFramewor
>   k.6.3.0\build\EntityFramework.props
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Packa

Answer (score 0):

Using a more recent version of Visual Studio will work. Also, downgrading to EF 6.2.0 worked for me, but I also need a better solution to this (i.e. one that lets me use 6.3.0) since I'm deploying to Azure and my site won't deploy unless I use 6.2.0.